# How can I do a validation if user back/forward in IE

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a website which needs login before viewing the main page, and here are two cases

1. user login successfully and redirect to main page, and then he click the "Back" button back to the login page, then click "Forward" button go back to the main page
2. user login successfully and redirect to main page, and then he types some other website like "www.google.com" in the addressbar to visit Google, then use the "Back" button to go back to the main page

How can i avoid these two cases from happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Page_Init in home page

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

and this in home page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Userid"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
            else
                Session["Userid"] = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: >        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
>        {
>           Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
>            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
>
>            if (Session["userid"] == null) Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
>        }

Comment: your first point can be solved if you check this in login pageload if(Session["userid"] != null) response.redirect("Default.aspx")

Comment: your second point cannot be solved because after accessing some other website press back button .the session is exist because browser not closed,so it redirect to home page instead of login page

Comment: But this is not i want. i want it to redirect to login page once go back to main page using "Back" button

Comment: @Khan, i cannot clear the session in that case, but thanks any way